# How to hide columns in Datagridview winform application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

How can I hide a column in datagridview like this:
[please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAjlZ.gif)

I searched for it in datagridview properties but found nothing.

Comment: Each column in the grid has a `Visible` property.

Comment: You could combine AllowUserToResizeRows with the Visible property to make a column invisible once its width is smaller that some pixels. Do think of a nice way to bring them back, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would jot down your requirement, I think you'd know the answer:

**Requirement** If the width of a column becomes 0 (or very small?), then the column should become invisible

```
const int minimumColumnWidth = 2; // can this be 0?
this.DataGridView1.ColumnWidthChanged += OnColumnWidthChanged;

private void OnColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = e.Column;
    column.Visible = column.Width > minimumColumnWidth;
}
```

Of course you have to invent a method to make the column visible again.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer sir but sir in my question description i have attached a GIF demo where we can hide column and make them visible again by double clicking. how can i achieve that kind of functionality? sorry for noob questions though and for bad english too.

Comment: I showed you: write down exactly what you want, and you will almost have the code to make it visible again. Something like: REQUIREMENT whenever the operator clicks ... the column must become visible again: so where and how should he click?